# A python class that is a 1-1 mapping of items, inheriting from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, inheritance

I am inheriting from the dict class and trying to make a 1 to 1 mapping of items.

Instead of key:value, i am trying to implement the **setitem** where given 
key1:key 2, key2:key1 is added as well. 
if either of the keys already exist, they should be popped before adding pairs. how could I implement **setitem**?

the **init** should be able to construct an empty mapping or one from a given dictionary

Any ideas? Thanks

```
class Mapping(dict):
    def __init__(self, Map = None):
        if Map = None:
            Map = dict()
        else:
            self.update(Map)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Mapping({})".format(dict.__repr__self)
    def pop(self):
        return self.pop   #??? How can I pop a key and also pop the key it maps to?
    def __setitem__(self, key1,key2):
        self.__dict__[key1] = key2
        self.__dict__[key2] = key1
```

Comment: `pop` should take an argument. dict.pop takes the key as argument

Comment: You also don't want to use `dict()` as the default value of `Map`; use `None`, and allocate a new `dict` *inside* `__init__` if `Map is None`.

Comment: If you have 1 mapped to 2 and 3 mapped to 4, and then you do `map[2] = 3`, what happens to the existing mappings? Do all of them get removed?

Comment: @user2357112 if key 1 or key 2 exists already then they should be popped before adding the pairs yes

Comment: NB: the dict update do not use setitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop` takes a key as an argument and returns the value associated with it. So take the value you get from popping key1, and pop that as key2.

You can just do `self.__dict__.pop(self.__dict__.pop(key))`

Comment: @TwistedSim why would this not work if key == value?

Comment: Because you'll be popping the key twice

Comment: In fact, you might need ‘key is item’ Would need a test!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

# We need to implement those method: __getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, __iter__, __len__

class TwoWayDict(MutableMapping):

    __slots__ = '__dict__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value
        self.__dict__[value] = key
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.__dict__.__delitem__(self[self[key]])            
        self.__dict__.__delitem__(self[key])  # this do not work if key == value
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)
    def get(self, key, default=None):
        return self[key] if key in self else default
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)
```

Tests:

```
a = TwoWayDict()
a['key1'] = 'key2'
print(a)
print(a['key1'])
print(a['key2'])
print(len(a))
for key, val in a.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Results:

```
{'key1': 'key2', 'key2': 'key1'}
key2
key1
2
key1 key2
key2 key1
```

Note that the length and iteration might be ambiguous. If you don't want duplicate key to show, you'll need to find the the key in the dict item and return the corresponding key. For pop you can use the solution propose by SW Williams.

EDIT: if you really need to inherit from dict (Probably an assignment...) don't forget to implement update, since it will bypass `__setitem__` and get in the dict. Also if you have a 1 to 1 map for on of the key, you need to deal with this in the `__del__` and `__pop__` functions.

Comment: Thanks, but i’m really trying to implement the __setitem__ using a dict, not a mapping

Comment: I must say, i you just implement the `__setitem__` most of the behavior you except won't work. Look at my edits in the answer above.